# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline' when trying to get all lines from a file

Tags: python, error-handling

trying to get all lines in a file and print them out

```
topic = 1
if topic == 1:
    allquestions = open("quizquestions1.txt","r")
    allquestions = allquestions.read()
    print(allquestions.readfile())
```

Comment: Use context manager for file interactions.

Answer (score 1):

It's only `allquestions` in print..You alredy read lines before no need to read again.

```
topic = 1
if topic == 1:
    allquestions = open("quizquestions1.txt","r")
    allquestions = allquestions.read()
    print(allquestions)
```

Comment: To add to this, when handling files it is strongly recommended to use the `with` keyword. Otherwise you have to remember to close the file again, which the code doesn't do

Answer (score 0):

The `read` method for a file will return the file content. You can use `help` function for it:

```
read(size=-1, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
    Read at most n characters from stream.
    
    Read from underlying buffer until we have n characters or we hit EOF.
    If n is negative or omitted, read until EOF.
```

It will return the content as a string containing whole file content.

```py
topic = 1
if topic == 1:
    with open("quizquestions1.txt","r") as file:
        allquestions = file.read()
        print(allquestions)
```

You can also use `readlines` method to get a splitted content of file based on `\n` character.